# trying to print loop in blade file but its not working

Tags: laravel

I am getting value from database and print as a loop in blade file but its not working

here is the code....

```
  <div class=" col-md-12 pt-10  list-sub-title mt-20" >
                           
      @php
                            
       $facts = $post_property->imp_facts;
                           
       @endphp
                
        @for ($i=0;$i<$facts;$i++)
         <p><img src="{{asset('images/PostProperty/ad-saved.png') }}" class="ft-img" style="">Feature 1   
          {{ $facts[$i] }} </p>
           @endfor
                    
       </div>
```

Anyone please help me to solve this..i shall be very thankful

I tried different things but doesnot find any solution yet.

Comment: what "is not working"? what are you expecting to happen and what is actually happening?

Comment: actually this column imp_facts contains number of data not just single value and  i am trying to print that data number wise like feature 1,feature 2 etc...but it doesnot print any thing

Comment: "number of data" as in an array? like its a JSON column? also it would print "feature 1 x, feature 1 x, etc"

Comment: number of data means lot of data...and its not integer value...its text value....and i want to print it as loop...hope you understand my point

Comment: so you want to iterate every character of a string?

Comment: yup....do you have any solution?

Comment: You need to count the $facts in your for statement || count($facts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to count $facts in your for loop by using count($facts):

```
<div  class="col-md-12 pt-10 list-sub-title mt-20">

    @php
        $facts = $post_property->imp_facts;
     @endphp

    @for ($i = 0; $i < count($facts); $i++)
        <p>
            <img src="{{ asset('images/PostProperty/ad-saved.png') }}" class="ft-img" style="">
            Feature {{$i + 1}}: {{$facts[$i]}}
        </p>
    @endfor

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to iterate through the elements of an array stored in $post_property->imp_facts and display them in a Blade template. However, you mentioned that it might not always be a numeric variable and could contain an array or objects.

Here are a few suggestions to improve your code:

1.Check if $facts is an array before using it in the loop:

```
<div class="col-md-12 pt-10 list-sub-title mt-20">
    @php
        $facts = $post_property->imp_facts;
    @endphp

    @if(is_array($facts))
        @foreach ($facts as $fact)
            <p><img src="{{ asset('images/PostProperty/ad-saved.png') }}" class="ft-img" style="">Feature 1 {{ $fact }}</p>
        @endforeach
    @else
        <p><img src="{{ asset('images/PostProperty/ad-saved.png') }}" class="ft-img" style="">Feature 1 {{ $facts }}</p>
    @endif
</div>
```

2.This modification checks if $facts is an array before attempting to loop through it. If it's not an array, it will display the single value.

Use @forelse for better handling of empty arrays:

```
<div class="col-md-12 pt-10 list-sub-title mt-20">
        @php
            $facts = $post_property->imp_facts;
        @endphp
    
        @forelse ($facts as $fact)
            <p><img src="{{ asset('images/PostProperty/ad-saved.png') }}" 
         class="ft-img" style="">Feature 1 {{ $fact }}</p>
        @empty
            <p>No facts available</p>
        @endforelse
</div>
```

@forelse is useful when you want to handle both the case of having elements and the case of an empty array.